# Changing the fill color of an Element in Gizeh

Tags: python, animation, cairo, moviepy

How can I change and/or get the fill color of an Element?

I would like to do something like this

```
import gizeh as gz

circle = gz.circle(10, xy = (100, 100), fill = (1, 0, 0))
circle.fill = (0, 1, 0)
```

I tried looking at the [source code](https://github.com/Zulko/gizeh/blob/d9fda97c9cc5508ecd3e6fbfa0590f763f4e2711/gizeh/gizeh.py), but got lost in context, transform_ctx etc. And can't find the part where the fill color is saved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you cannot change the color after-the-fact.

Calling `gz.circle()` eventually ends up calling `shape_element`: https://github.com/Zulko/gizeh/blob/d9fda97c9cc5508ecd3e6fbfa0590f763f4e2711/gizeh/gizeh.py#L378-L448

This function has the `fill` argument and defines a function `new_draw` that draws the element. This `new_draw` function uses `fill`.

So, basically your question is equivalent to:

How can I make the following print 42?

```py
def get_func(value):
    def func():
        return value
    return func

my_func = get_func(21)
# What can I insert here to change the value to 42?
print(my_func())
```

I think the answer to my own question is "not possible".